# How to force a change in option of <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use `$('select').change(function(){alert('changed');});` for issue an alert every time the `option` is changed, but i need to alert even the default option, that is, in the first option of `option`

```js
$('select').change(function(){
  alert('changed');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
  
</body>
</html>
```

How to print alert when the first option("volvo") is loaded, but it did not come from a change?

P.S.:Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just trigger your change event once loaded. I copied your snippet below and just added `.trigger('change')`, you'll notice `volvo` will alert onload.

```js
$('select').change(function(){
  alert(this.value);
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just call the `change` handler manually one time upon page load. With JQuery, that can be done with the **[`.trigger(event)` method](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)**.

```js
// When the DOM is ready...
$(function(){

  $('select').on("change", function(){
    alert('changed');
  });
  
  $('select').trigger('change');

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `trigger` `change` event for it

```js
$('select').change(function(){
  alert($('select').val());
}).trigger("change");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
  
</body>
</html>
```